# Can I derive a class from `std::array`?

Tags: c++, queue, derived-class, stdarray

In general standard container classes are not intended to be derived from, e.g. they have non-virtual destructors.

However, I noticed that `std::array` does not define a destructor at all (at least in the GNU library).

Does it mean `std::array` is safe to derive from?

I do not intend to overload any of its member functions, just add a few more (mainly to use it as a fixed size queue).

Comment: If a class doesn't define a destructor the compiler will generate a (trivial) default destructor. The default destructor is not virtual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is safe to derive from a class with non-virtual destructor *non-publicly*. It is only public inheritance that is potentially unsafe.

`std::array` has a destructor regardless of whether one has been declared. All classes have destructors. It is *always* UB to delete an object through a base class pointer if the base class destructor isn't virtual. `std::array` is not different in that regard.

Comment: Using protected or private inheritance gives me no advantages compared to composition. I still have to reimplement all base class's public member functions... don't I?

Comment: @Pietro Correct.

Answer (score 4):

The virtual destructor is only required if you are going to use polymorphism and `delete` your new class as a `std::array`. This probably isn't your use-case. If it is, you're out of luck.

Not sure how much of the existing `std::array` functionality you require so this might not be a good option for you, but the general purpose recommendation is to prefer composition over inheritance. Use the `std::array` as a member of a class that adds the new functions you want and exposes the existing `std::array` functionality that you require.